# Cannot run rails server on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’m working on getting my first rails application, but for whatever reason, when I run the command $rails server, my terminal throws back this error:

```
C:\Sites\blog>rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/r
ubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2
adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bu
ndle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (requir
ed)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb
:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb
:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb
:25:in `spec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb
:130:in `establish_connection'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3
.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Sites/blog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Sites/blog/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/blog/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from C:/Sites/blog/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/Sites/blog/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

How can I solve the problem?
My Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]
Rails version: 3.2.13
gem --version: 1.8.24

Comment: Please show your Gemfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's see what is written in the output.

*mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.*

I think it means that mysql2 is not part of the bundle, and you should add it to Gemfile in order to fix this error.

Open Gemfile, add `gem 'mysql2'` to it, run `bundle install`, `rake db:create && rake db:migrate`, and then `bundle exec rails server`.